# Find last date of months for different years

Tags: stata

I have a string variable with years and months:

```
clear

input str6 year
"2012m5"
"2013m9"
"2014m10"
"2015m12"
"2016m2"
"2017m8"
"2018m6"
end
```

When I apply the solution provided in a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772102/find-last-date-of-year), the results do not make sense:

```
g date = dofy(monthly(year, "YM") + 1 ) - 1
form date %td 

l

     +--------------------+
     |   year        date |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 2012m5   31dec0628 |
  2. | 2013m9   31dec0644 |
  3. | 2014m1   31dec0648 |
  4. | 2015m1   31dec0660 |
  5. | 2016m2   31dec0673 |
     |--------------------|
  6. | 2017m8   31dec0691 |
  7. | 2018m6   31dec0701 |
     +--------------------+
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `year` is really not a good variable name for a monthly date.

Answer (score 0):

@PearlySpencer focuses on what to do. Here I focus on what was wrong in your code. Simple commands allow you to look at what was done and work out what the error was.

```
clear 
input str6 year
"2012m5"
"2013m9"
"2014m10"
"2015m12"
"2016m2"
"2017m8"
"2018m6"
end

generate step1 = monthly(year, "YM") 

list, sep(0) 

     +----------------+
     |   year   step1 |
     |----------------|
  1. | 2012m5     628 |
  2. | 2013m9     644 |
  3. | 2014m1     648 |
  4. | 2015m1     660 |
  5. | 2016m2     673 |
  6. | 2017m8     691 |
  7. | 2018m6     701 |
     +----------------+
```

The `monthly()` function produces a monthly date on a scale for which `0` is January 1960.

Adding `1` first and subtracting `1` later don't make any substantial difference to the main error, which was feeding that result to `dofy()`, which expects a year(ly date) as input and produces a daily date as output. That's why you got daily dates for years that were wildly wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i find these functions quite confusing.

Comment: The function names, although often abbreviated, are informative. Even experienced users keep going back to the help every time there's a puzzle. Those are the only reasons we know the answers!  `help dofy()` specifically and `help datetime` generally explain.